# Charging Magic Mouse 2 when the device is turned off…

Tags: hardware, mouse

Simple question.

Can I turn off my **Magic Mouse 2** when I'm charging it's battery through the cable?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can turn it off while charging.

However, according to Apple:

> For the fastest battery charging performance, be sure your device is
>   switched on when connecting the Lightning to USB cable.

**Source:** [Recharge the built-in battery in your Apple accessory](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT205160)

Comment: OK. I did a test during the night. Mouse was fully charged while turned off. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I normally turn mine off so my computer, which is nearby, won't acquire it thru bluetooth.