# What is the maximum wattage/amperage the Magic Mouse 2 can consume?

Tags: mouse, charging

Oddly I have to charge these things a lot and I'm trying to determine which power of AC-USB charger to buy without being wasteful.

For example, if I use a 12W (2.4 amp) iPad charger, will the magic mouse consume all 12W, or will it use a stepped-down trickle like 2.5 watts from the 12 watt charger?

Apple doesn't seem to list this info anywhere.

Comment: Define "wasteful"?

Comment: This does not directly your answer your question, but may be a solution to your actual problem. [Apparently the MM2 charges faster when switched on.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/284630/45492) Did you try that?

Comment: @IconDaemon Say I have to charge 10 magic mice at any given time. I could spend $15-per-port for a huge 12W adapter (total $150), or spend $4-per-port for a 6W adapter 60Wx10Port charger (total $40). Now multiply this by floors in a building and buildings on a campus.

Comment: You should edit your question to indicate that you're dealing with many MM, not just one or two, which was my assumption.

Comment: Looking at the fact that you want to charge many mice, I would get a [USB voltmeter](https://www.amazon.com/DROK-Multimeter-Multifunctional-Electrical-Capacity/dp/B00J3JSEG6/ref=pd_bxgy_107_img_3/144-6994870-4019524?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00J3JSEG6&pd_rd_r=b6126fa1-8887-4fd1-9982-028791ac317a&pd_rd_w=jWJU3&pd_rd_wg=ZhmC0&pf_rd_p=a2006322-0bc0-4db9-a08e-d168c18ce6f0&pf_rd_r=253BSEGHN0YZFTZ6RDRX&psc=1&refRID=253BSEGHN0YZFTZ6RDRX), test the wattage, and purchase accordingly. There seem to be no specs out there. Make sure to answer your question :-)

Comment: @n1000 great idea... thanks for doing the search for a good one to buy, ordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [USB voltmeter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00J3JSEG6) (at @n1000's recommendation), this is the Magic Mouse 2 consumption rounded to the nearest 10th:

**0.5 Amps (2.5 Watts) while switched off**

[image: Apple mouse charging while off]

**1.5 Amps (7.5 Watts) while switch on**

[image: Apple mouse charging while on]